# Как ограничить множественный выбор по select ?

Tags: jquery, select

Есть такая конструкция:

```
<select id="elements_itemcategoryvalue" name="elements[_itemcategory][value][]" title="Категория" size="15" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;Элемент 1</option>
    <option value="4">&nbsp;&nbsp;.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;Подменю 1-1</option>
    <option value="3">&nbsp;&nbsp;.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;Подменю 1-2</option>
    <option value="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;Подменю 1-3</option>
    <option value="5">&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;Элемент 2</option>
    <option value="10">&nbsp;&nbsp;.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;Подменю 2-1</option>
    <option value="9">&nbsp;&nbsp;.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;Подменю 2-2</option>
    <option value="8">&nbsp;&nbsp;.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;Подменю 2-3</option>
    <option value="7">&nbsp;&nbsp;.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;Подменю 2-4</option>
    <option value="11">&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;Элемент 3</option>
</select>
```

Можно выбрать несколько элементов, удерживая шифт или ctrl
Подскажите, как можно ограничить вы выбор селектов к примеру до 3х, а так же запретить выбор для селекта "Элемент" - т.е. выбрать можно только "Подменю *-*" и только 3 селекта..

Comment: @Павел Решетов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

"Элемент 1" - Тег

Запретить выборку больше трех можно с помощью Javascript. Посчитать количество выбранных элементов и сделать то что нужно.

[Сначала проверяйте есть ли такой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/37170/javascript-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-select)

Comment: Да, спасибо.. но как этот лемент преобразовать в optgroup.. мне его выдает cms.. =\

Comment: Это тяжелый случай))Посмотрите шаблон (как выводится) и измените его.

Comment: ок )) а как на счет ограничения?

Comment: Запретить выборку больше трех можно с помощью Javascript. Посчитать количество выбранных элементов и сделать то что нужно.

Comment: запретить выборку можно запретив выборку..) спасибо, как я сам не допер ))

Comment: А вы что предлагаете мне за вас это сделать? )) как я сам не допер ))
Я же не знаю что вы знаете)

Как я понимаю js вы не знаете. а тут нужно с ним поработать

Comment: Исправил ответ выше. там я вам ссылку дал.